# Installing scion in emacs

Tags: haskell, emacs, cabal, cabal-install, haskell-mode

I am looking to install the `scion` for my emacs. However as the README suggests, when I run `cabal install` the following error pops up:

```
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following will be installed:
scion-0.3 (reinstall) changes: atto-lisp-0.2.1.1 added, attoparsec-0.10.4.0
added
Warning: Note that reinstalls are always dangerous. Continuing anyway...
Configuring scion-0.3...
Building scion-0.3...
Preprocessing library scion-0.3...

src/Scion/Cabal.hs:30:18:
    Could not find module `GHC.Paths'
    There are files missing in the `ghc-paths-0.1.0.9' package,
    try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
scion-0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

running ghc-pkg check gives:

```
There are problems in package scion-0.3:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/scion-0.3/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/scion-0.3/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Scion/Cabal.hi is missing
  file Scion/Ghc.hi is missing
  file Scion/Session.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Compiler.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Commands.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Core.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Monad.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Note.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Session.hi is missing
  file Scion/Types/Worker.hi is missing
  file Scion/Utils/Convert.hi is missing
  file Scion/Utils/IO.hi is missing
  file Scion/Worker/Commands.hi is missing
  file Scion/Worker/Main.hi is missing
  file Paths_scion.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSscion-0.3.a on library path
There are problems in package atto-lisp-0.2.1.1:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/atto-lisp-0.2.1.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/atto-lisp-0.2.1.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Data/AttoLisp.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSatto-lisp-0.2.1.1.a on library path
There are problems in package blaze-textual-0.2.0.8:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/blaze-textual-0.2.0.8/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/blaze-textual-0.2.0.8/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Blaze/Text.hi is missing
  file Blaze/Text/Double.hi is missing
  file Blaze/Text/Int.hi is missing
  file Blaze/Text/Double/Native.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSblaze-textual-0.2.0.8.a on library path
There are problems in package vector-0.10.0.1:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/vector-0.10.0.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: include-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/vector-0.10.0.1/ghc-7.4.2/include doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/vector-0.10.0.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Data/Vector/Internal/Check.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Fusion/Util.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Size.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream/Monadic.hi is missing                                                                                                                                          
  file Data/Vector/Fusion/Stream.hi is missing                                                                                                                                                  
  file Data/Vector/Generic/Mutable.hi is missing                                                                                                                                                
  file Data/Vector/Generic/Base.hi is missing                                                                                                                                                   
  file Data/Vector/Generic/New.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Generic.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Primitive/Mutable.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Primitive.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Storable/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Storable/Mutable.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Storable.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Unboxed/Base.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Unboxed/Mutable.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Unboxed.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector/Mutable.hi is missing
  file Data/Vector.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSvector-0.10.0.1.a on library path
There are problems in package unix-compat-0.3.0.2:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/unix-compat-0.3.0.2/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: include-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/unix-compat-0.3.0.2/ghc-7.4.2/include doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/unix-compat-0.3.0.2/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file System/PosixCompat.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/Extensions.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/Files.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/Temp.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/Time.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/Types.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/Unistd.hi is missing
  file System/PosixCompat/User.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSunix-compat-0.3.0.2.a on library path
There are problems in package network-2.3.2.0:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/network-2.3.2.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: include-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/network-2.3.2.0/ghc-7.4.2/include doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/network-2.3.2.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Network.hi is missing
  file Network/BSD.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket/ByteString.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket/ByteString/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket/Internal.hi is missing
  file Network/URI.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket/ByteString/IOVec.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket/ByteString/MsgHdr.hi is missing
  file Network/Socket/ByteString/Internal.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSnetwork-2.3.2.0.a on library path
There are problems in package parsec-3.1.3:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/parsec-3.1.3/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/parsec-3.1.3/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Text/Parsec.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/String.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/ByteString.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/ByteString/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Text.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Text/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Pos.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Error.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Prim.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Char.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Combinator.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Token.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Expr.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Language.hi is missing
  file Text/Parsec/Perm.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Char.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Combinator.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Error.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Expr.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Language.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Perm.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Pos.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Prim.hi is missing
  file Text/ParserCombinators/Parsec/Token.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSparsec-3.1.3.a on library path
There are problems in package mtl-2.1.2:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/mtl-2.1.2/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/mtl-2.1.2/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Control/Monad/Cont.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Cont/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Error.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Error/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Identity.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/List.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/RWS.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/RWS/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/RWS/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/RWS/Strict.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Reader.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Reader/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/State.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/State/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/State/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/State/Strict.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Writer.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Writer/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Writer/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Writer/Strict.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSmtl-2.1.2.a on library path
There are problems in package transformers-0.3.0.0:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/transformers-0.3.0.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/transformers-0.3.0.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Control/Applicative/Backwards.hi is missing
  file Control/Applicative/Lift.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/IO/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Class.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Cont.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Error.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Identity.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/List.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Maybe.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Reader.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/RWS.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/RWS/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/RWS/Strict.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/State.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/State/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/State/Strict.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Writer.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Writer/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Control/Monad/Trans/Writer/Strict.hi is missing
  file Data/Functor/Compose.hi is missing
  file Data/Functor/Constant.hi is missing
  file Data/Functor/Identity.hi is missing
  file Data/Functor/Product.hi is missing
  file Data/Functor/Reverse.hi is missing
  cannot find libHStransformers-0.3.0.0.a on library path
There are problems in package blaze-builder-0.3.1.0:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/blaze-builder-0.3.1.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/blaze-builder-0.3.1.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Int.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Word.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/ByteString.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Char/Utf8.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Char8.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Html/Utf8.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/HTTP.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Internal.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Internal/Write.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Internal/Types.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Internal/Buffer.hi is missing
  file Blaze/ByteString/Builder/Internal/UncheckedShifts.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSblaze-builder-0.3.1.0.a on library path
There are problems in package attoparsec-0.10.4.0:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/attoparsec-0.10.4.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/attoparsec-0.10.4.0/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Data/Attoparsec.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/ByteString.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/ByteString/Char8.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/ByteString/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Char8.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Combinator.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Number.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Text.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Text/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Types.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Zepto.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/ByteString/FastSet.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/ByteString/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Internal/Types.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Text/FastSet.hi is missing
  file Data/Attoparsec/Text/Internal.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSattoparsec-0.10.4.0.a on library path
There are problems in package text-0.11.2.3:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/text-0.11.2.3/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/text-0.11.2.3/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Data/Text.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Array.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding/Error.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Foreign.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/IO.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Builder.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/Int.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/RealFloat.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Encoding.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/IO.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Read.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Read.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding/Fusion.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding/Fusion/Common.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding/Utf16.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding/Utf32.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Encoding/Utf8.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Fusion.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Fusion/CaseMapping.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Fusion/Common.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Fusion/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Fusion/Size.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/IO/Internal.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/Functions.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Builder/RealFloat/Functions.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Encoding/Fusion.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Fusion.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Lazy/Search.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Private.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Search.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Unsafe.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Unsafe/Base.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/UnsafeChar.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/UnsafeShift.hi is missing
  file Data/Text/Util.hi is missing
  cannot find libHStext-0.11.2.3.a on library path
There are problems in package temporary-1.1.2.4:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/temporary-1.1.2.4/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/temporary-1.1.2.4/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file System/IO/Temp.hi is missing
  file Distribution/Compat/Exception.hi is missing
  file Distribution/Compat/TempFile.hi is missing
  cannot find libHStemporary-1.1.2.4.a on library path
There are problems in package primitive-0.5.0.1:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/primitive-0.5.0.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  Warning: include-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/primitive-0.5.0.1/ghc-7.4.2/include doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/primitive-0.5.0.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Control/Monad/Primitive.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/MachDeps.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/Types.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/Array.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/ByteArray.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/Addr.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/MutVar.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/Internal/Compat.hi is missing
  file Data/Primitive/Internal/Operations.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSprimitive-0.5.0.1.a on library path
There are problems in package multiset-0.2.1:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/multiset-0.2.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/multiset-0.2.1/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file Data/MultiSet.hi is missing
  file Data/IntMultiSet.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSmultiset-0.2.1.a on library path
There are problems in package ghc-paths-0.1.0.9:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/ghc-paths-0.1.0.9/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/ghc-paths-0.1.0.9/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file GHC/Paths.hi is missing
  cannot find libHSghc-paths-0.1.0.9.a on library path
There are problems in package canonical-filepath-1.0.0.2:
  Warning: library-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/canonical-filepath-1.0.0.2/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  import-dirs: /home/sudeep/.cabal/lib/canonical-filepath-1.0.0.2/ghc-7.4.2 doesn't exist or isn't a directory
  file System/FilePath/Canonical.hi is missing
  cannot find libHScanonical-filepath-1.0.0.2.a on library path

The following packages are broken, either because they have a problem
listed above, or because they depend on a broken package.
scion-0.3
atto-lisp-0.2.1.1
blaze-textual-0.2.0.8
vector-0.10.0.1
unix-compat-0.3.0.2
network-2.3.2.0
parsec-3.1.3
mtl-2.1.2
transformers-0.3.0.0
blaze-builder-0.3.1.0
attoparsec-0.10.4.0
text-0.11.2.3
temporary-1.1.2.4
primitive-0.5.0.1
multiset-0.2.1
ghc-paths-0.1.0.9
canonical-filepath-1.0.0.2
```

Comment: For some reason GHC thinks that `ghc-paths-0.1.0.9` is installed on your system, but cannot find the module `GHC.Paths` (which actually is the *only* module provided by that package). Perhaps running `ghc-pkg check` as suggested will help?

Comment: @kosmikus please look at the edit.

Comment: This is looking rather bad. Lots of libraries you have installed (according to `ghc-pkg`) aren't actually present on your system. Did you remove your `.cabal` directory at some point?

Comment: unfortunately yes. I was looking to reinstall ghc, cabal, haskell mode and scion. When I saw the .cabal folder, I thought that wasn't required.

Comment: So you should probably wipe the `.ghc` directory in your homedir as well, to clear your user-specific `ghc-pkg` database.

Comment: So what do I need to install after that.